# Pierre et pélot et pésin

Tags: prononciation

Je finissais le dernier des mots de la liste Swadesh, "pierre", et je suis resté bloqué devant les réponses présentes dans les images dont les liens sont ci-dessous.

https://ibb.co/ZMm5r81
https://ibb.co/pn6vBsM

En tant que francophones, pouvez-vous me dire s'ils ont une origine commune ?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Il y a confusion sur le sens à donner au mot ***pierre***.

La carte de l'[Atlas linguistique de la France](http://lig-tdcge.imag.fr/cartodialect5/#/) où on retrouve *pelot* représente le mot utilisé par les personnes sondées à la fin du XIX<sup>e</sup> siècle en parler local (ici du [Gallo](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gallo)) pour nommer une personne dont le nom en français est **Pierre** (masculin). ***Pélo*** et ***Pélot*** sont simplement ici des variantes du diminutif ***Pierrot*** (plus proche de ***Perrot*** ici). La représentation phonétique **/pezɛ̃/** apparaît elle une seule fois en Savoie. C'est celle d'un aubergiste de [Hauteluce](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hauteluce) en 1900. On n'est plus dans le domaine de la langue d'oïl mais dans celui de l'arpitan ([franco-provençal](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Francoproven%C3%A7al)). Il ne peut s'agir là aussi que d'une variante très locale du prénom Pierre (probablement dérivée de ***Perrin***).
*Pélo* et *pézin* ne sont donc pas des prononciations du nom commun ***pierre*** qui par ailleurs est féminin.

Le substantif ***pierre*** est rendu soit par le même ***pierre***, soit par ***caillou***, soit par ***roc*** avec les variantes dialectales et de prononciation des régions respectives.

[image]

Il faut aussi être bien conscient que ces cartes sont très éloignées de celles qui pourraient être réalisées aujourd'hui, le vocabulaire s'étant fortement homogénéisé et les accents et langues régionales s'étant fortement atténués au cours des cent-vingt ans qui se sont écoulés depuis que cet atlas a été conçu.

Comment: Merci beaucoup. Je voulai voir cette carte, mais oubliai

Answer (score 1):

Je suis désolé. Je ne sais pas ce qu'est la liste Swadesh. Je ne sais même pas ce que tu appelles "une origine commune". Les mots basés autour de la racine "pierre" en français viennent presque tous du latin "petra, -ae", lequel s'est progressivement face à "lapis" (qu'on retrouve en français dans des mots comme "lapidaire", ou "lapis-lazuli", par exemple).

Par ailleurs, quand je recherche la liste Swadesh du français, je trouve [une liste](https://abcdufrancais.com/2022/06/04/lexique-de-base-du-francais-la-liste-swadesh/) de 100 mots (ceux en gras) ou de 207 mots (gras et fins conjugués), parmi lesquels on ne trouve pas "pierre". Mais si je comprends bien le principe de la liste Swadesh, que j'ai survolé très rapidement, alors oui, la racine de pierre est commune.

Edit : En poursuivant mes recherches, j'ai retrouvé des listes de Swadesh dans lesquelles le mot "pierre" figure en 156ème position.

Comment: seulment celui de 100 mots peut être utiliser pour analiser des langues. pierre est le 77ème là. Mais aux images, il y a les reponses [pəlo] et [pəzè~]. Et je m demande s'ils prennent l'origine d'un ou différant mots Latin

Comment: Ok. If you'd rather switch to English or another language, that would be fine by me as well. So I'm not sure how to interpret these pictures. I can see a "carte départementale" of France, including what I'm guessing are various forms of "pierre" in French regional toponomy? A bit of context could help: what are we looking at, here?

Most of these forms I've never seen or heard in my life. "Pelo" sounds like the French word "peler" (to peel off, to shed off), which comes from latin "pilare" (to clear the skin, to rid of the hair), itself from "piluse (hair).

Comment: As for "peser", it comes from vernacular low-latin "pensare", itself from latin "pendere". It means "to weigh" in both acceptions of the English word : both, to appraise the weight of something, or to be weighty. The latin root found earlier, pendere, is the same you'll find in French "pendre" (to hang, to hang something)

Comment: It turns out I confused maps

Comment: Alright. Well, if you need help with anything else, be sure to let me know. Take care, man.